# Flask running on a VM not reachable from outside

Tags: python, flask, server, virtual-machine

I have a strange Flask issue. I have a simple app running on port 5000 which is running on a VM. I have a `config.py` file which is setting the listening port and IP. This is my config:

```
class BaseConfig(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key_which_is_not_so_secret'
    SERVER_NAME = '0.0.0.0:5000'

class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True

class TestConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = True
```

And I have also included the following line in my `__init__.py` file: `app.config.from_object('config.DevConfig')`. When I start the app, this is the log:

```
$ python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "webapp" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: XXX-XXX-XXX
/home/ubuntu/programming/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py:217: UserWarning: The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work as intended in some browsers. Add an entry to your hosts file, for example "localhost.localdomain", and use that instead.
  'The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work'
my.ip.add.ress - - [04/Dec/2018 10:09:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
my.ip.add.ress - - [04/Dec/2018 10:09:17] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018 10:15:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018 10:16:28] "GET /netemulator HTTerror 404 -
```

So when I try to reach it from my PC, I get 404 errror, the same error I got when I try to internally reach it with `elinks`. If I delete the `SERVER_NAME` line in the `config.py` I can reach it from within the VM using `elinks` and I can see that it is properly loading but I can't reach it from my PC.

```
$ python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "webapp" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: XXX-XXX-XXX
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018 10:18:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018 10:18:36] "GET /netemulator HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Where is your VM running ? I had exactly same issue running Flask (v1.1.1) on EC2. Removing SERVER_NAME from configs and adding `host='0.0.0.0'` in `app.run()` worked for me. If you're on AWS EC2, make sure you have allowed inbound rules for port 5000.

Comment: that did the trick